# How to uninstall dangerous MSI package

Tags: uninstall, windows-installer

I am developing a program in C#. I am using `Advanced Installer` to create MSI install package for my program.

`Version 1` of my MSI install package was creating shortcut to my program in Windows `Start Menu`. On uninstall I wanted it to delete this shortcut from Start Menu folder, but I made something wrong and it deletes whole `Start Menu` folder instead of shortcut to my program.

Now I want to spread `Version 2` of my MSI install package. But before installation of `Version 2` `Version 1` must be uninstalled first – and here the problem comes to light. I don't want my users to loose their `Start Menu`...

Is there any way to solve this situation?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here. But your question is also too broad. How do you think people can answer you without knowing your code / settings?

Comment: Why does it NEED to uninstall? You can set Adv Installer to install over the top of the other msi. Perhaps set delete options to remove stuff you don't want to keep and just update the stuff you do.

Comment: @MátéJuhász - It's not a coding question bud, it's a 'I didn't test something properly and now need some advice' question

Comment: You're right @JoeTaylor. I didn't test it properly first. This could be the solution for me: to set Advanced Installer to install over the top of other msi.  So how can I do this? (I don't want to change my Product GUID.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a custom action in your MSI that does the shortcut deletion? If so the only reliable way I know of is to patch the installed product with a **MSI minor upgrade** to eliminate this custom action from running on uninstall. When this update has been installed, you can uninstall the product and the problem custom action should no longer run.

In technical terms the minor upgrade will transform the cached MSI database on the system so that the uninstall custom action won't run. This is quite involved to do if you haven't done it before, but it is a "working procedure". It all depends on your MSI skill level.

How big is your user base?